# Error de compilacion en g++ con hilos

Tags: c++, hilos

Soy nuevo compilando en g++ y tengo un error cuando compilo hilos, miren este código

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func(){
    cout << "funciona" << endl;
}

int main(){
    thread t1(func);

    if(t1.joinable()){
        t1.join();
    }
}
```

Cuando lo compilo me surge este error

```
    hilos.cpp: In function 'int main()':
hilos.cpp:11:5: error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope
     thread t1(func);
     ^~~~~~
hilos.cpp:13:8: error: 't1' was not declared in this scope
     if(t1.joinable()){
        ^~
```

he revisado el codigo varias veces y no se porque surge ese error, lo estoy compilando con

```
g++ hilos.cpp -mthreads
```

He oido de -pthreads, -lpthreads pero no me funcionan

Uso Windows 10 y g++ 6.3.0

```
g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Si necesitan mas informacion sin problema que la verdad lo necesito urgente.

O si es posible me recomiendan otro compilador para c++ en consola

Comment: ¿Has probado con `-pthread`?

Comment: ya probé y no funciona. ¿A ti te funciona?

Comment: A mi me funciona, [efectivamente](https://tio.run/##RY7BDoIwDIbvfYpGLyMEE84g7zK7gTXQEbd5Mby6cxONvf1fvv4trWszEaV0ZKE5Got9uN6tNgP8CTsfMlsGgOhZJhS9WL9qsuiD6QAejg2OUUhVT8A85GLAvsdDgexEH0qyYuYONgCWgItm@en7SQytKn6VGwvlUYX2dHMs@jJbVX3lz8LOVVZL3GBL6UXjrCefmnWvS01@7kx13bZv "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online").

Comment: ¿como escribirías en la terminal para compilar un archivo llamado hilos.cpp igual al código que puse en la pregunta?

Comment: Bueno, usaría un IDE en lugar de complicarme la vida con la línea de comandos. Pero si me viera obligado a usar la línea de comandos escribiría `gcc archivo.cpp -std=??? -pthreads`. Respecto al parámetro `std` dependerá de tu compilador, la cabecera `<thread>` fue incorporada en C++11 así que puedes escribir `-std=c++11`, `std=c++14`, `std=c++17` o `std=c++2a`, depende de lo que acepte tu compilador.

Comment: me sale un    error gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-pthreads'; did you mean '-mthreads'?

Comment: que ide usas, dev-c?

Comment: No compilo gcc porque no lo tengo instalado. Pero en las pruebas que uso en compiladores online a mi me funciona con `-pthread`.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108501/discussion-between-juuamjskn-and-paperbirdmaster).